# Ajax load to only load one of multiple classes on page

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

So on my page i have many blog posts that are all editable on the page.

When you click edit a text editor is displayed and then on clicking save the editor goes away and the original text comes back.

However, i want the text of the original post to reload to show the new information.

This:

```
$targetForm.find('.divid').load('page.php .divid');
```

Works fine if there is only one div on the page, but if there is more than one all of the posts get loaded into the currently editing div.

How can i do the same sort of thing as $targetForm.find but for the div to update?

So like:

```
$targetForm.find('.divid').load('page.php $targetForm.find('.divid')')
```

That sort of thing.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

try to handle the `click` event first before updating the div :

```
$targetForm.find('.divid').on('click', function(){
    $(this).load('page.php .divid');
});
```

Comment: can you post your `page.php` code ? and also the page which is using ajax !